# How do I get the Android Notification ID for an FCM notification?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM flutter library.

In addition I am trying to use flutter_local_notifications library to clear a notification based on the Android notification id.

The problem is, is that the FCM library does not seem to expose the android notification id, which is required to cancel the notification.

Is there anyway, at the flutter level, which I could get the android notification id?

Comment: have you tried using the notification channel?

Comment: I don't want to clear an entire channel, just a single notification.